# Overlapping Polygon becoming hole when converting geojson to shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, geojson, osgeo

I'm trying to convert a geojson MultiPolygon which contains two overlapping polygons to a shapefile, however I noticed that the resulting shape has a smaller area. Upon inspection it's because the overlapping polygon is becoming a hole in the shapefile. Do I need to change a setting or do something different to preserve the overlapping polygon? I'm using GDAL 1.10.1 and the following code:

```
def convert():
    data = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [
                    [[[-98.7, 49.6], [-98.7, 49.7], [-98.8, 49.7], [-98.8, 49.6], [-98.7, 49.6]]],
                    [[[-98.74, 49.64], [-98.74, 49.66], [-98.76, 49.66], [-98.76, 49.64], [-98.74, 49.64]]]
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {}
            }
        ]
    }

    geometry = []
    if (data['type'] == 'FeatureCollection'):
        for feature in data['features']:
            geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(json.dumps(feature['geometry']))
            print 'Geom Area', geom.GetArea()
            geometry.append({
                'geometry': geom})

    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    res = srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    print 'Import Res', res
    data_source = driver.CreateDataSource('out.shp')

    layer = data_source.CreateLayer('shape-layer', srs, ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
    featureDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
    layerDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
    for data in geometry:
        feature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
        feature.SetGeometry(data['geometry'])
        layer.CreateFeature(feature)
    data_source.Destroy()
```

Viewing the geojson and resulting shapefile in QGIS, this is what I see:

Initial Geojson

[image: Initial Geojson]

Resulting Shapefile

[image: Final Shapefile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason for your problem is that the MultiPolygon in your source data is invalid because it has nested shells. In the OGC standand for Simple features MultiPolygon is defined as:

> 6.1.14 MultiPolygon
>
> A MultiPolygon is a MultiSurface whose elements are Polygons. The
>   assertions for MultiPolygons are as follows.
>
> a) The interiors of 2 Polygons that are elements of a MultiPolygon may
>   not intersect.
>
> b) The boundaries of any 2 Polygons that are elements of a
>   MultiPolygon may not “cross” and may touch at only a finite number of
>   Points.

You can't define your geometry as MultiPolygon but you must wrap it inside GeometryCollection. As WKT a valid presentation would be

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (
    POLYGON ((
            -98.7 49.6, 
            -98.8 49.6, 
            -98.8 49.7, 
            -98.7 49.7, 
            -98.7 49.6
        )), 
    POLYGON ((
            -98.74 49.64, 
            -98.74 49.66, 
            -98.76 49.66, 
            -98.76 49.64, 
            -98.74 49.64
        )))
```

Answer (score 2):

The shapefile format does not know the "MultiPolygon" geometry, replaced by a Polygon geometry.

I use here [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html)  and [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) (much easier than ogr, many examples in GIS.SE)

```
data = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-98.7, 49.6], [-98.7, 49.7], [-98.8, 49.7], [-98.8, 49.6], [-98.7, 49.6]]],[[[-98.74, 49.64], [-98.74, 49.66], [-98.76, 49.66], [-98.76, 49.64], [-98.74, 49.64]]]]},"type": "Feature","properties": {}}]}
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping
multi =  shape(data['features'][0]['geometry'])
print multi.wkt
MULTIPOLYGON (((-98.7 49.6, -98.7 49.7, -98.8 49.7, -98.8 49.6, -98.7 49.6)), ((-98.74 49.64, -98.74 49.66, -98.76 49.66, -98.76 49.64, -98.74 49.64)))
```

There are 2 polygons in the MultiPolygon

```
for poly in multi:
     print poly
POLYGON ((-98.7 49.6, -98.7 49.7, -98.8 49.7, -98.8 49.6, -98.7 49.6))
POLYGON ((-98.74 49.64, -98.74 49.66, -98.76 49.66, -98.76 49.64, -98.74 49.64))
```

Save the geometry to a shapefile

```
import fiona
# schema of the shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'MultiPolygon','properties': {'id': 'int'}}
geom = data['features'][0]['geometry']
print geom
{'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[-98.7, 49.6], [-98.7, 49.7], [-98.8, 49.7], [-98.8, 49.6], [-98.7, 49.6]]], [[[-98.74, 49.64], [-98.74, 49.66], [-98.76, 49.66], [-98.76, 49.64], [-98.74, 49.64]]]]}
# save to a shapefile
with fiona.open('multipol.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema)  as output:
     output.write({'geometry':geom,'properties': {'id':1}})
```

Now open the shapefile

```
multi = fiona.open('multipol.shp')
# first feature
first = multi.next()
print first
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-98.7, 49.6), (-98.8, 49.6), (-98.8, 49.7), (-98.7, 49.7), (-98.7, 49.6)], [(-98.74, 49.64), (-98.74, 49.66), (-98.76, 49.66), (-98.76, 49.64), (-98.74, 49.64)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1)])}
```

[image]

Therefore the MultiPolygon consisting of two Polygons is replaced in the shapefile by a Polygon consisting of two parts = a Polygon with hole

```
coords =  first['geometry']['coordinates']
for coord in coord:
     print coord
 [(-98.7, 49.6), (-98.8, 49.6), (-98.8, 49.7), (-98.7, 49.7), (-98.7, 49.6)]
 [(-98.74, 49.64), (-98.74, 49.66), (-98.76, 49.66), (-98.76, 49.64), (-98.74, 49.64)]
```

#### Conclusion

Modify your geometry or don't use shapefiles

```
 schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'id': 'int'}}
 # save to a shapefile
  with fiona.open('polys.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema)  as output:
      # split multipolygon
      for poly in multi:
           output.write({'geometry':mapping(poly),'properties': {'id':1}})
```

[image]

Comment: I do not believe that limitations of the shapefile format have any role in this play. MultiPolygon which has overlapping parts is simply an invalid geometry.